# imprimir el primer elemento que se encuentra dentro de mi último elemento en mi vector

Tags: javascript, array

Como hago para imprimir el primer elemento que se encuentra dentro de mi último elemento en mi vector?

```
let vectores = [];   
vectores = ["Mi nombre","Mi apellido",["algo","nuevo"]];

console.log("Array:",vectores[2]);
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias describir mas claramente tu problema? eso es solo un pedazo de codigo, que es lo que le pasa?

Comment: `console.log("Array:",vectores[2][1]);`

Comment: En realidad sería `vectores[2][0]`.

Answer (score 1):

En ese array seria:

```js
let vectores = ["Mi nombre","Mi apellido",["algo","nuevo"]];
console.log(vectores[2][0]);
```

Ahora bien, esto es porque conoces el largo del array, sin conocer el largo de antemano podría ser alguna de las siguientes formas:

```js
let vectores = ["Mi nombre","Mi apellido",["algo","nuevo"]];

console.log(vectores[vectores.length-1][0]);
console.log(vectores.at(-1)[0]);
console.log(vectores.at(-1).at(0));
```